# Finding and changing a number suffix on strings in a loop

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

There has got to be an easier way to do simple string manipulations than what I'm coming uo with. I have a method that allows users to duplicate a file in the directory. if they select it in the table view and press the clone button a copy of the file will save and the fileName will be appended with the substring Copy. If  Copy already exist then we need to iterate the filename and append the file name by the loop iteration. For example;

```
<filename> Copy 1
<filename> Copy 2
until my other method return that the name is unique.
```

I need to examine the passed in filename for three criteria;
does it already have "Copy" appended to it
does it already have a string number appended to it
if so, get the value of the number iterate it by one and put it back.

After quite a while, I could only come up with this:

```
//Tokenize the string
NSArray *filenameArray =[copyName componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

//Make sure the name is unique
//Update the namesArray
[self montageNameList];
int i = 1;
for(NSString * name in self.montageNames){

    if([channelSetManager_ checkNoDuplicateName:self.montageNames forThisName:copyName]== YES){
        break;
    }else{

        if([[filenameArray lastObject]isEqualToString:@"Copy"]){

            //Just add a number to the end of the string
            copyName = [copyName stringByAppendingFormat:@" %d", i];

        }else if(([[filenameArray lastObject]intValue] > -1) && ([[filenameArray lastObject]intValue] < 100)){

            i = [[filenameArray lastObject]intValue]+1;
            NSInteger len = [[filenameArray lastObject]length]+1;
            copyName = [copyName substringToIndex:[copyName length] - len ];
            copyName = [copyName stringByAppendingFormat:@" %d",i];
        }

    }


}
```

This works but does not seem like the correct way. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is actually not a bad implementation at all: the problem itself is not pretty, so the algorithm that solves it cannot be pretty either.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have created a temporary file using `mkstemp()`, then linked to the temp file to the permanent file, attempt next file name if link fails with file exists, repeat until link succeeds, and unlink the temporary file.

```
// Finds next available copy name and creates empty file as place holder
- (NSString *) createCopyFileWithBasename:(NSString *)baseName andSuffix:(NSString *)suffix
{
    char tmpFile[1024];
    char copyFile[1024];
    int  fd;
    int  count;

    // create unique temporary file
    snprintf(tmpFile, 1024, "%s.XXXXXXXX", [baseName UTF8String]);
    if ((fd = mkstemp(tmpFile)) == -1)
    {
       NSLog(@"mkstemp(): %s", strerror(errno));
       return(nil);
    };
    close(fd);

    // attempt to create empty file for file copy
    snprintf(copyFile, 1024, "%s Copy.%s", [baseName UTF8String], [suffix UTF8String]);
    switch(link(tmpFile, copyFile))
    {
       case EEXIST: // file exists, skip to next possible name
       break;

       case: 0: // excellent, we found an available file name
       unlink(tmpFile);
       return([NSString stringWithUTF8String:copyFile]);

       default:
       NSLog(@"link(): %s", strerror(errno));
       unlink(tmpFile);
       return(nil);
    };

    // loop through possible iterations of file copy's name
    for(count = 1; count < 1024; count++)
    {
       snprintf(copyFile, 1024, "%s Copy %i.s", [baseName UTF8String], count, [suffix UTF8String]);
       switch(link(tmpFile, copyFile))
       {
          case EEXIST: // file exists, skip to next possible name
          break;

          case: 0: // excellent, we found an available file name
          unlink(tmpFile);
          return([NSString stringWithUTF8String:copyFile]);

          default:
          NSLog(@"link(): %s", strerror(errno));
          unlink(tmpFile);
          return(nil);
       };
    };

   unlink(tmpFile);
   NSLog(@"link(): %s", strerror(errno));

   return(nil);
}
```

Example usage:

```
NSString copyFileName = [self createCopyFileWithBasename:@"My Data" andSuffix:@".txt"];
```